# 叱られる時に「うるさい！」と「やかましい！」のどちらがきついですか？

Tags: dialects, word-usage

辞書では意味がとても近いので、聞きたいのですが、例えば、ビニール袋などで音を立てている時に、知らないおっさんに急に「うるさい！」または、「やかましい！」って言われたら、その言葉のチョイスで叱られた感は違いますか？

また、そのキツさは「あほ」と「ばか」のように地域・方言によって変わりますか？

Answer (score 1):

東日本の人にとっては「うるさい」のほうがありふれた言葉なので直感的に響くということはあると思います。ただ、それがそのまま叱られた感につながるかは、人によりけりと言ったところではないでしょうか。私にはどっちもどっちです。

関西の人にとっては「やかましい」もありふれた言葉なのでしょうが、私にはそのあたりはよくわかりません。